# how to tell the difference between a JUnit @Before and the test

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests, junit4

I want to be able to tell the difference between the code that executes in a JUnit @Before method and the code that executes in the actual test.

I've looked into extending TestWatcher, but the starting(Description) method is called before the @Before starts executing and not right before the Test starts.

Ideally I'm looking for this situation:

```
A: [arbitrary code]
B: JUnit @Before method
C: [more arbitrary code]
D: JUnit @Test method
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "tell the difference"? Is the same code in both places?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have code that knows at run-time where it was called from?  Or do you just mean that you've got an exception, or something, and you don't know which block of code the problem is in?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to vary code behaviour dynamically depending on whether a test is initialising or running, you could try getting the stack trace of the current thread and stepping through the frames until you find one where the method is annotated with either `@Test` or `@Before` (or `@BeforeClass`).

Alternatively, you could create a new test class runner (probably extending `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`) and annotate your test class with `@RunWith(MyTestClassRunner.class)` to use it.  A good article on how to do this is here: http://tedyoung.me/2011/01/23/junit-runtime-tests-custom-runners/